# Finding character in a string in less than O(n)

Tags: c++, string, performance, search, time-complexity

Is it possible to search a character in a string in less than O(n). Most of the algorithms I have come across takes O(n) time. string::find() takes O(N*M). Is there any algorithm in which you are not required to traverse the whole string.

Comment: Not unless your string is sorted.

Comment: If you can sort your string, you can use binary search.

Comment: Such an algorithm can't possibly exist. If there were an algorithm that doesn't examine every character, I could construct input that puts the target in precisely the spot the algorithm skips.

Comment: You can check `Boyer Moore string search algorithm` which has best case time complexity of `Omega`(N/M)

Comment: but in my case, i want to search for a single character not a substring or pattern, so for this specific problem even the Boyer Moore string search algorithm will take same as O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Well first I must say there isn't algorithm less than linear O(n) time complexity for your problem.

Of course you can try randomized algorithm like Las Vegas way of thinking. Pick a random spot from your array if lucky you found your char if not try again and store the wrong index.

Worst case is like linear search O(n) but purely lucky if you get it in few first tries it's way less. This kind of algorithm maybe is what you are looking for. On average it will find char maybe faster but remember if it still takes k tries when for sure k < n it is still linear time. O(k)

If you know more from your input ***maybe*** you can think of way to solve it differently.

Hope this helps